# Why does Xcode line-out autocomplete methods for selector?

Tags: swift, xcode

Ever since I upgraded to the latest Xcode, autocomplete lines out (strikethrough) methods for the `selector` object. I cannot tell if this is a bug with Xcode or there is some new syntax change I'm unaware of. If you plug this into your Playground and erase the method inside `#selector(tapHandler(_:))` and re-enter it, does autocomplete line-out the <strike>`tapHandler(_:)`</strike> suggestion or not?

```
class Mango {
    func tap() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHandler(_:)))
    }

    @objc func tapHandler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say it's a bug — especially because you can still select the crossed-out `tapHandler` and the code then compiles and runs correctly.

Comment: Nicely spotted @acidgate - same thing happens for me.  Even if you import UIKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of typing `tapH` and asking for autocomplete, type `self.tapH` and ask for autocomplete. The problem goes away.

So, yes, I do rather think it's a bug (unless Swift is changing so that you can't omit the class in a method reference), but there's also an easy workaround.